# IsBranch in tfs api is alway false

Tags: tfs

I'm using the tfs api and have a need to check if a provide path is a tfs branch

I'll spare the full code but it gets down to

```
m_VersionControlServer.GetItem(source).IsBranch
```

For whatever reason this always returns false. Am I missing something or is just broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call one of the overload's of `GetItem()` that has a [`GetItemsOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.getitemsoptions.aspx) parameter and pass in `GetItemsOptions.IncludeBranchInfo`.

For example:

```
var isBranch = 
    m_VersionControlServer.GetItem(
         path: source
         version: VersionSpec.Latest,
         deletedState: DeletedState.NonDeleted,
         options: GetItemsOptions.IncludeBranchInfo).IsBranch;
```